# How to Properly Configure Apache on a SPA React App that Resides on a Subdirectory that uses Nested URLs built from React Router?

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router, react-router-dom

I have my website hosted on a subdirectory, as an example, http://mywebsite/admin, where /admin is the subdirectory

I have my react app (create-react-app production build) uploaded into the /admin subdirectory. I am also using react-router v4 BrowserRouter to have some simple client-side routing performed. Below are some relevant snippets on my react-app:

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import './css/custom.css';

ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter basename="/admin"><App /></BrowserRouter>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

**inside App.jsx render function**

```
<Route
    path='/students'
    render={(props) =>
        <Students
            {...props}
        />
    }
/>

<Route
    path='/teachers'
    render={(props) =>
        <Teachers
            {...props}
        />
    }
/>
```

All is well and working when navigating the site including the nested urls which are mainly, as you have seen on the snippets, `/admin/students` & `/admin/teachers`.

**The main issue:** when I am on the `/admin/teachers` route and I **refresh the page**, the page does not load anything. Refreshing works when I am on `/admin` route only. But not when it is `/admin/teachers` nor `/admin/students`.

This is not the first time I have built an SPA using react-router v4 hosted on Apache server. I have reused the .htaccess I have on my previous project. This .htaccess also resides at the `/admin` subdirectory. Below is the `.htaccess`:

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This routes all requests to the index.html built by the create-react-app production build. However, upon my investigations, this type of configuration only works on a project that is not on a subdirectory and is not using nested URLs.

Note, that I have 2 `.htaccess` now. One on root and another one at the `/admin` subdirectory. **Both contain the same `.htaccess` codes**. The reason for this is, I have another SPA running at the root directory.

What am I missing?

How to Properly Configure Apache on a SPA React App that Resides on a Subdirectory that uses Nested URLs built from React Router?

Comment: "This routes all requests to the index.html" - It currently routes all requests to `/index.html` in the document root, not the `/admin` subdirectory? Is that the intention? (Although I would have expected - and would be preferable - for everything to be in the `/admin` subdirectory?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primarily addressing the [OP's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62889356/10265109), plus some other notes...

> This is where I made a mistake:
>
> > Note, that I have 2 .htaccess now. One on root and another one at the
> > /admin subdirectory. Both contain the same .htaccess codes. The reason
> > for this is, I have another SPA running at the root directory.

This wasn't necessarily a "mistake" - you would just need to make sure you are using the correct directives. In fact, keeping the two `.htaccess` files separate could be preferable if these are intended to be entirely separate SPAs.

To have two separate - identical - `.htaccess` files the important points are:

- Make the substitution string *relative*, ie. no slash prefix.
- Do not include a `RewriteBase` directive. (Which would override the directory-prefix.)

When the `RewriteRule` *substitution* string is a *relative* path then the directory-prefix (ie. the location of the `.htaccess` file) is added back at the end of the rewriting process.

So, both `/.htaccess` and `/admin/.htaccess` would contain identical directives:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.html?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

HOWEVER, a slight difference with this solution and the OP's solution is that the `admin/` part of the URL-path is not passed to the `path` URL parameter. You could hardcode this if required. eg. `index.html?path=admin/$1`. Or account for this in your script.

The first `RewriteRule` is just a minor optimisation that prevents further filesystem checks after the request has already been rewritten to `index.html`.

Note that I changed `(.*)` (0 or more) to `(.+)` (1 or more). This avoids the additional directory check when requesting the root directory. ie. `example.com/` and `example.com/admin/`. You are not rewriting these requests, but instead are reliant on `DirectoryIndex index.html` being set appropriately - this is the default setting in the server config.

Since the *substitution* string (`index.php?page=$1`) is relative, when in the document root it will effectively rewrite to `/index.php` and when in `/admin/.htaccess` it will effectively rewrite back to `/admin/index.php`.

Note that the mod_rewrite directives in `/admin/.htaccess` completely override the mod_rewrite directives in the parent `.htaccess` file since mod_rewrite directives are not inherited by default (unlike other modules).

---

Alternatively, to avoid repetition, whilst still maintaining two separate `.htaccess` files you could enable mod_rewrite inheritance in the `/admin/.htaccess` file. For example...

In the root `/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.+) index.html?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then, in `/admin/.htaccess` you would have the following instead:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit
```

This *inherits* the parent mod_rewrite directives as if they were literally copied in-place in the `/admin/.htaccess` file.

However, this adds an additional layer of complexity. Apart from the SPA in `/admin` now being dependent on the root `.htaccess` file, you now have to be careful that you don't add any *breaking* directives to the root `.htaccess` file.

---

*Aside:*

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule (.*) admin/index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule (.*) index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]
> ```

The first condition that checks for "admin" in the URL-path (incidentally, this checks for "admin" *anywhere* in the URL-path - which isn't strictly correct) is not required - the check can be performed more optimally in the `RewriteRule` directive itself. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^(admin/.*) admin/index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

These two rules can be combined into one if desired, possibly at the expense of some clarity. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(admin/)?.* $1index.html?path=$0 [QSA,L]
```

The `$1` backreference then contains the optional path-prefix, either `admin/` or *nothing*. And `$0` contains the full match.

Answer (score 2):

This is where I made a mistake:

> Note, that I have 2 .htaccess now. One on root and another one at the
> /admin subdirectory. Both contain the same .htaccess codes. The reason
> for this is, I have another SPA running at the root directory.

Simply **adjusting** my root `.htaccess` **and deleting** the `.htaccess` that was inside the /admin subdirectory fixed the main issue described on my question.

**Root .htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} admin
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) admin/index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: In the code you've posted the `$1` backreference is always empty (resulting in an empty `path` URL param) as you've omitted the capturing group from the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ (as you had in your original code).

Comment: Incidentally, you could have kept the two separate (identical) `.htaccess` files, one in the `/admin` subdirectory and one in the root. However, you would just need to make sure you removed the slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` _substitution_ (as you have done here) - to avoid the request always being rewritten back to root. ie. `RewriteRule (.*) index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]` in _both_ files. Without the slash prefix, the rewrite is relative to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file. The mod_rewrite rules in the `/admin/.htaccess` file override the rules in the parent (by default).

Comment: If you wanted, you could also employ mod_rewrite inheritance to inherit the parent directives "in-place" - this saves having to duplicate the directives from the parent `.htaccess` file, although does introduce some complexity. (Although using inheritance may not be desirable if you wish to keep the installations entirely separate - but combining the two `.htaccess` files has the same issues in this respect.)

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite. I've edited my answer to fix the `$1` backreference issue. I've also tested your 2nd comment regarding two separate `.htaccess`. This also worked. Thanks for this information that could possibly help future users. If you want, you can also write a more robust answer if you deem necessary.

Comment: I've added an answer that goes into more detail. Note that with the "two separate `.htaccess` files as I suggested above", the `admin/` prefix would not be passed to the `path` URL parameter, whereas, in your solution (using a single `.htaccess` file in the root), it is. Note sure if that would be an issue for you - but it could be added if required.

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know the answer to your problem, but I can suggest you to *play* with `Location` directive; something like

```
<Location "/admin">
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /admin/index.html?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
</Location>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you sir. You helped me arrive to my answer. Bounty awarded.

Comment: The `Location` directive is not permitted in `.htaccess` files - only in a server or virtualhost context. Consequently, this will result in a 500 error. You don't need the `location` directive here as you can do the appropriate pattern matching in the `RewriteRule` directive. ie. `RewriteRule ^(admin.*) /admin/index.html?path=$1 [QSA,L]`

Comment: Can you help edit/salvage this answer @MrWhite (for future viewers). I've already awarded the bounty. The RewriteRule here technically helped me arrive to an answer.