# ReactJS production with subfolder, navigation not working properly

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router, router

I'm struggling to make my ReactJS production work in a subfolder of my website.

The dashboard works, when I go to http://xx.xx.xx.xx/dashboard it loads, but when I go to
http://xx.xx.xx.xx/dashboard/login I get a 404 not found page. When I host in the main folder it works perfectly.

As far as I know to make it work I have to set the basename of the subfolder in the Router of index.js,
which I did. Am I missing anything? I used "npm run build" to make the production.

index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <MuiThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router basename={"/dashboard"} history={history}>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        <Notifs />
        <MainContent />
    </div>
  );
}
```

MainContent.js

```
export default function MainContent() {
  return (
    <div className="container" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: In case you are using Apache, I've solved this issue recently: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62727936/how-to-properly-configure-apache-on-a-spa-react-app-that-resides-on-a-subdirecto/62945237

Comment: @eric I'm using a webhost (Linux CentOS 7 unmanaged to be precise). Is it an Apache specific solution or could it apply to my problem as well?